# Is there a notification function for new Google Ops Agent releases

Tags: stackdriver

For my GCP environment, I am having trouble keeping up with google Ops Agents constant updates. I would like to find a way to get notified every time a new release is pushed out.. That way I won't be left with legacy versions. [Example of legacy versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AbhU.png)

Comment: One method is to GitHub subscribe to new releases: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.